# Trying to add a text field to a small layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to insert a text field or button into a small layout bar but for some reason its not showing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d1cbcb">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#767eca">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text = "Ankosh"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what exactly is not showing?

Comment: why close relativeLayout after background? if the textview should inside, than there´s no need to...

Comment: Provide orientation- vertical or horizontal to linear layout.
If you want to specify some height to textview, its better to provide it to textview itself other than the parent layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the height of the inner relative layout or mark it as `wrap_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d1cbcb">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#767eca">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text = "Ankosh"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change layout_height to wrap_content and if you want textview height 50dp then use that inside TextView

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#767eca">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text = "Ankosh"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
```